# Different methods need different attributes in one object

Tags: java, design-patterns, constructor, builder

I have a given web service. (This is only an example, the real one is more complex, but it has the same problem.) The service has three methods and all three methods have a person as parameter and need other things from it. (I can't change the entity or methods.)

Entity (Person) (It has only a default constructor):

```
private String name;
private int age;
private Address address;
private List<String> hobbies;
private List<Person> friends;
```

- Method1 needs name and age.
- Method2 needs address name and age.
- Method3 needs all.

I need to fill the object from my own objects. I need to write a "converter". What is the best practice for it?

My solutions:

- Builder Pattern with builds for three methods.
- Set all attributes and send unhandled overhead (bad solution in my eyes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Creating a builder that sets only required fields sounds good.
2. You can inherit from this class for each of your needs and implement your own constructors

   ```
   public class Target {
       // fields
   }

   public class Purpose1 extends Target {
       public Purpose1(String name, int age) {
           // set fields or do whatever you wish
       }
   }

   public class Purpose2 extends Target {
       public Purpose2(String address, String name, int age) {
           // set fields or do whatever you wish
       }
   }

   public class Purpose3 extends Target {
       public Purpose3(...) {
           // set fields or do whatever you wish
       }
   }
   ```

And then you may use instances of subclasses where class `Target` is required.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get what you want with a suitable usage of decorator pattern:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern